# ASP Parser Error after adding LocalResource file to a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm working in VS2012 on an ASP.NET web forms project. I have created a user control named Trips.ascx. I had VS auto-generate a local resource file for me (Trips.ascx.resx). After adding the resource file, I cleaned it up to only contain the properties/values I need. It ran just fine. Then I duplicated the resource file and named it Trips.ascx.pt.resx to support Portuguese. Now for some reason when I run the project, I get a Parser Error as described below:

**Parser Error Message:** Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridBoundColumn' does not have a public property named 'HeaderTextpt'.

I'm not sure what it is appending "pt" to the "HeaderText" property.

Any thoughts/suggestions as to why I am receiving this error?

**UPDATE:** I notice that if I create an empty resource file named Trips.ascx.pt.resx, then no errors are thrown. It is only when I start to add entries with the same Name as they are referenced in the control itself (ex: when I add "CaloriesLabelResource1.Text" as a resource key to the Trips.ascx.pt.resx)

For reference, my folder structure is as follows:

> -Project
>
> --Controls
>
> ---App_LocalResources
>
> ---Trips
>
> ----App_LocalResources
>
> -----Trips.ascx.pt.resx
>
> -----Trips.ascx.resx
>
> ----Trips.ascx
>
> ...

Here is the code using calling the resource:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" 
    ID="MyTripsGrid" 
    OnNeedDataSource="MyTripsGrid_NeedDataSource" 
    AllowPaging="True" >
    <MasterTableView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="DateColumn" HeaderText="Date" DataField="Rented" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" meta:resourcekey="DateGridBoundColumnResource1" />
```

Comment: I should add that both resource files have their Build Action set to Content.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are referring to the `GridBoundColumn.HeaderText`?

Comment: Just updated my post. It works just fine when there is only the single Trips.resx file. I only receive the error when I try adding other languages (I also tried Trip.es.resx but to no avail)